# Firebase Cloud Messaging : My application doesn't receive the messages that i sent

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to integrate FCM to my app. Actually I'm getting the token, but when I send a message to the app, apparently it don't receive the message sent.

I'm new developing in Android and I hope that someone can help me telling me what is wrong.

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="snowf.app.celixxx">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <!-- This permissions are neccessary for broadcast receiver -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="snowf.app.celiguide.support.fcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:node="replace">


           <service android:name="snowf.app.xxxxxxx.GCMNotificationIntentService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="snowf.app.xxxxxxx.MyFireBaseInstanceIDService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="true" />

        <!-- Broadcast receiver declaration in manifest file and make sure to enable it -->
        <!--
             <receiver
                 android:name=".modules.offlineStorageModule.broadcast.ConnectivityBroadcast"
                 android:enabled="true">
                 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
     -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.com.vansuita.pickimage.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/picker_provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name=".modules.splash_.PreSplashScreen">

            <!-- Todo: uncomment intent filter here after done testing to different screens and remove filter form other activity -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".modules.login.smsverifcation.SmsVerificationPhoneNumberScreen"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".modules.home_.HomeActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:label=""
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

            <!--
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            -->
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".modules.home_.QRScannerScreen"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".modules.splash_.SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".modules.language_select.SelectLanguageScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".modules.language_select.PickLanguageScreen"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".modules.login.LoginScreen"
            android:label=""
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".modules.login.ForgotPassword"
            android:label=""
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".modules.login.ForgotPasswordChangeScreen"
            android:label=""
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".modules.login.SignupScreen"
            android:label=""
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="3225xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`
My GCMNotificationIntentService.class is:

```
package snowf.app.celixxxxxxx;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends FirebaseMessagingService
{
    public static final int MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 435345;
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String from = remoteMessage.getFrom();
        Log.d("ON MESSAGE", "Message from:" +from);
}

// Creates notification based on title and body received
private void createNotification(RemoteMessage.Notification notification) {
    Context context = getBaseContext();
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new         NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
            .setContentText(notification.getBody());
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Finally my MyFireBaseInstanceIDService.class is:

```
package snowf.app.celixxxxxxx;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

import static snowf.app.celixxxxxxx.support.CeliGuideApp.TAG;



public class MyFireBaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService     {


    private static final String TAG = MyFireBaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    if (refreshedToken!=null) {
    //    SettingPreferences.setStringValueInPref(this, SettingPreferences.REG_ID, refreshedToken);
    }
    // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}



// [END refresh_token]

/**
 * Persist token to third-party servers.
 *
 * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
 * maintained by your application.
 *
 * @param token The new token.
 */
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // Add custom implementation, as needed.
}}
```